# Bash: printing program output to file, not on screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash file to spin a few servers for me. I want all the program std output to be generated by the running servers to be saved in the file, and not printed by bash on the screen. This is how I wrote my bash file:

```
#!bin/sh

rm -rf database.db

go run server.go -typ=server -id=Server1 -host=localhost -port=9998 | tee logs/Server1.log &
go run server.go -typ=server -id=Server2 -host=localhost -port=9999 | tee logs/Server2.log &
go run server.go -typ=server -id=Server3 -host=localhost -port=9998 | tee logs/Server3.log ;
```

When i run `bash my_script.sh` the output is indeed written to .log files, however the same output is still printed on the screen. How I can fix it?

Comment: If you don't want to print output on terminal then use `go run server.go -typ=server -id=Server1 -host=localhost -port=9998 > logs/Server1.log &` Don't use `tee`

Comment: Do you know what `tee` does? Why are you using it if you don't want it to do its normal thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tee` commands redirect the output to both the standard output and to a file.

If you want the log to be redirected to just the file then use `>` like `my_command > out_file`

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly send stdout to file without needing to add any tee commands in shell script

Eg. If you shell script is named database.sh
Then in terminal execute

```
./database.sh > output.txt
```

The above command will delete any existing contents of output.txt

Or

```
./database.sh >> output.txt
```

This will append the output to content of output.txt if any

The latter will be helpful if you wish to run shell script multiple times and keep log of every run